# Python: Urllib keeps booleans capitalized when using urllib.parse.urlencode()

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a dict of arguments I want urllib to parse, so I am using `urllib.parse.urlencode()`. However, when one of the arguments is a bool, it keeps the bool capitalized in the result, which doesn't work with what I'm trying to do.

```py
>>> import urllib
>>> args = {'foo': True, 'bar': False}
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(args)
'foo=True&bar=False'
```

Desired result: `'foo=true&bar=false'`

What's the best way to resolve this? I could just fix it manually by looping through `args` and replacing each bool with a lowercase string but I feel like there's a better way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Why would you expect it to downcase? `str(True)` returns `'True'`, not `'true'`, and all `urlencode` does with non-strings is convert them to strings using `str` before encoding them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shortcut for this. As the `urlencode` method accepts a sequence of pairs (tuples), it is in theory more efficient to not rebuild a dictionary, but pass this list as argument:

```
[(k, str(v).lower() if isinstance(v, bool) else v) for k, v in args.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but it will depend a little on what you want;

You may be able to simply call `.lower()` on the resulting string, but note this will change everything to lowercase, which may break something else (ie. this will break YouTube references because they rely on the capitalization to encode more information)

```py
urllib.parse.urlencode(args).lower()
```

Otherwise rebuild your dict with either a comprehension or directly changing the values

Refer to [**@trincot**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905795/4541045) for this

Comment: Note that `0 in (True,False)` is true. This does not have an adverse effect in this case, but it seems cleaner to really check whether the value is an instance of `bool`.

Comment: Ah, your answer with `isinstance()` is probably cleanest there, though a proper loop may become better with growing complexity (though URLs have a finite text limit, so it probably doesn't matter) (I've cleaned off my suggestions for now and just refer to yours)